# Cassandra cross dc for high availability

Tags: database, cassandra

we have a 3 node Cassandra cluster in 1 DC
and we have a another DC (in the same city) with another Cassandra cluster (but cassandra isn't installed on this machines)
So we want Cross-DC only for high availability in case of (DC outage, Fire, Water flooding etc)
According to docs the DC in the cassandra is logical and main purpose of it to be a closer to clients, but we doesn't want this feature
so should i split Cluster to Multi-DC or use 1 DC in this case? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to split your cluster in 2 data-centers, this fits well your requirements, DC is meant is a logical separation of your data, but it is also inspired from real physical DC, so it is also designed for high availability.

Depending on your data and requirement, you can imagine maybe 3 replicas per data center, read/write with LOCAL_QUORUM, so all your client application need is 2 live replicas per data-center to keep running.

The the trad off, between consistency, high availability and partition tolerant is handled by your number of node/data-centers, you replication factor, and your consistency level.

I think that multi data-centers is a good choice for you.

Here is a link that might help you understanding the relation between replication factor, consistency level and hight availability

http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=13216

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you my friend! but problem is we already have some keyspaces in the cassandra, with replication factor 1 and without any snitch options for Multi-DC so recreate this Keyspaces will be mess

Comment: You are welcome, I understand but you cannot have availability with a replication factor of 1, I think you will have to face the mess and handle it once for good.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-DC is a good idea for distributed database like Cassandra. It provides many benefits like availability, fault tolerance and low latency. It will also help in Disastrous scenario for backup and restoration. if you want to add another DC in your existing cluster you can add easily with following procedures below:-

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html . However, decision is yours that what you want to do.

https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/distributed-database-things-know-cassandra-datacenter-racks